# android - How to arrange the two textviews side by side

Tags: android, textview

I have two text views(TV_1,TV_2).I want to set the TV_2 is immediate right of the TV_1.
It means

1. suppose TV1 occupy the one entire line in the screen then TV2 will set below the TV1.
2. Suppose Tv1 occupy the one and half line then tv2 will occupy the rest of the space. How to implement this? i tried but i am not getting. It is similar to one paragraph.

[image]

```
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/xrays_dicom_alert_TnC" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp">                            

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/xrays_dicom_alert_cb"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>     


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/xrays_dicom_alert_TnC_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/xrays_dicom_alert_cb"             
            android:text="I have read I agree to the following"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />  
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/xrays_dicom_alert_statement"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/xrays_dicom_alert_cb"
            android:layout_below="@id/xrays_dicom_alert_TnC_text"
            android:layout_alignRight="@id/xrays_dicom_alert_TnC_text" 
            android:text="Statement"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />     

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Please post your layout xml file.

Comment: why do you want this ? You can also do this using single text view as i see your xml.

Comment: i want to set the second text view is clickable.

Comment: @naresh any solution to this?

Answer (score 2):

Thats impossible act in Android.

A View occupies a rectangular area on the screen.

http://www.androidadb.com/class/android/view/View.java.html

Or you have to do something like this

[image]

To make clickable some text in TextView one can go with *Spannable* concept.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Spannable.html

use `URLSpan` http://www.androidadb.com/class/ur/URLSpan.html

Comment: i think it is open in browser but i want to open using web view how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

I think it's not possible in the pattern what you have asked.